# Can i add the https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/ to load from our local server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am working on an Asp.net MVC core web application, which work as an internal application (users might access the application without internet access), and i added the Tiny rich text editor from this link https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/ . but seems this rich text editor will only load/work if the users are connected to the internet. so my question is if i can force this rich text editor to work and load locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can download the Tiny Editor files and host them on your own webserver.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#sdkinstall

You can also [install via NuGet](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#nuget) (or NPM etc).